# Difference between ampersand (&) before or after command arguments

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, shell, cygwin

I am a Windows user and I am using Cygwin as my terminal. In order to run notepad++ from terminal I have added this lines to ~/.bash_profile:

```
npp () {
    /cygdrive/d/Notepad++/notepad++.exe $(cygpath -w -- "$@")
    }
```

it worked, so next I needed a way to launch it on the background so I could open a npp++ instance without stopping my terminal flow. This worked:

```
npp foo &
```

But I did not want to introduce that ampersand manually, so I tried adding this alias to ~/.bash_profile:

```
alias npp="npp &"
```

And now:

```
npp foo
```

Works in the background.

The problem is that with gnu/linux commands you need to write ampersand after the arguments, if not it will not work.

this works:

```
ls directory &
```

This doesnt:

```
ls & directory
```

So I would like to know what am I missing here, because:

```
npp foo
```

Actually works in the background when I set

```
alias npp="npp &"
```

And it does not when I comment it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following command is launching in the background the `ls` executable passing `directory` as its single argument, this is what you want to do:

```
ls directory &
```

That one is launching `ls` in the background without any argument and then is (trying to) launch `directory` as a command in the foreground, this is not what you want to do:

```
ls & directory
```

Using an `alias` doesn't change this behavior, unless `cygwin` `sh` has a specific feature I'm unaware of, which I strongly doubt.

Comment: You are right, I have tested that 'ls & directory' just list current directory and then throws an error for missing 'directory' command. So, why 'npp foo' works as 'npp foo &' when 'npp' is an alias to 'npp &'?

Comment: It doesn't work with `bash` under Linux, I didn't test under `cygwin` but I would be very surprised if it behaves differently.

Comment: thank you, I was missing something: I run notepad++ without -nosession and -multiinst options, so whenever it is opened it remembers last session files. As I have always been testing it with the same file, it was always loaded, so 'npp foo' was already 'npp & foo', which ignores 'foo', but foo appears on notepad++ because it was loaded on last session. what a misunderstood, thanks!